# attachments are not posting in facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook

i am geting some text from webservices and need to post that text on the wall of facebook.

my text is like this.

```
Wall Street traders who make bets with a firm's own money usually have at least several sets of bosses looking over their shoulder.At MF Global Holdings Ltd., where <phrase name="Corzine, Jon S." significance="PROMINENT" type="PERSON" vrtysux="PERSON|Corzine, Jon S.">Jon S. Corzine</phrase> made $6.3 billion in trades on European sovereign debt that sank the company last month, a different set of rules applied.
```

while trying to post this as caption it is not posting.

But if it is plain text then it posting well.

here is the code for posting title,message with link.

```
dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"name\":\"%@\",\"href\":\"%@\",\"caption\":\"%@\"}", postTitle,postTitleLink, postMessage];
```

I think with the format of text is the problem if it is can any one please tell how can i resolve it if it not what may be the problem.

Thank u in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:
NSString *description = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Wall Street traders who make bets with a firm's own money usually have at least several sets of bosses looking over their shoulder.At MF Global Holdings Ltd., where Jon S. Corzine made $6.3 billion in trades on European sovereign debt that sank the company last month, a different set of rules applied."];

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               APP_ID, @"app_id",
                               @"Test Posting",@"name",
                               @"www.google.com", @"link",
                               description, @"description",nil];

[self.facebook dialog:@"feed" andParams:params andDelegate:self];
```

**If your link contains double quote then it must be converted in utf8 string and then add to the params.

Comment: No we can not add manually, i need to convert above string like as you said,In my string it contains <>,how can i remove them